# How to convert values that are only TRUE or FALSE into checkboxes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to convert only values that are TRUE or FALSE like this

[image: this]

into checkboxes so that it looks like this

[image: this]

in google sheets?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about programming. Consider asking at [webapps.se] instead, if you're looking for general usage.

Answer (score 0):

select cells by holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and mouseclicking:

[image]

and then insert them like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think he has a long range

Comment: @Osm if so, then only with script I guess